# How do I use SCSS variables with data-attributes in Vue JS and Bootstrap Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to have a Dark Theme button on my application and change the whole theme in a click. It is already working but I wanted to find an easier way to accomplish that.

I have created a button in the navbar that sets a localStorage variable to "dark" or "light" on click. Upon loading the application, its store will read the localStorage and have it available to the whole application.

Excerpt from store.js:

```
state {
   ...
   theme: localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light',
   ...
}
```

In my application, if I want to change the theme to a breadcrumb, I would do:

```
<b-breadcrumb :data-theme="theme">
    <b-breadcrumb-item active>Start</b-breadcrumb-item>
</b-breadcrumb>

import {mapState} from 'vuex'
export default {
    ...
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['theme'])
    }
}
```

and in the custom.scss file:

```
[data-theme="dark"] {
    $breadcrumb-bg: $dark !important;
}
```

And it would have changed the whole component color.

This does **NOT** work.

---

However, this **DOES**:

```
.breadcrumb[data-theme="dark"] {
  background-color: $dark !important;
}
```

---

My question is: **Is there an easy way to change all components using data attributes and SCSS variables or do I have to mannually select classes and change the components I want?**

Comment: have you tried `*[data-theme="dark"]`?

Comment: @D.Schaller , works with artifacts. Apparrently it only works on css directives directly, not using sass variables. What I mean is `*[data-theme="dark] { background-color: $dark }` works. `*[data-theme="dark] { $breadcrumb-bg: $dark }` does not. Your suggestion, is good, but I fear it would give me more work than I wanted because I don't want to change all components (*), but only some components.

Comment: If you only attach the data-theme attribute to the elements you want to have changed, then it should be no problem going with `*[data-theme="dark] { background-color: $dark }` If you want to style different objects differently when using dark-mode, then you have to create multiple selectors and rules anyway.

Comment: @D.Schaller, thank you for your help but I will not be able to do what I want because the specification for the data attributes will not allow them to use sass variables, it expects a DOMString.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use Sass variables in custom data attributes as I wanted because the specification for data attributes won't allow them. They expect a DOMString name, not a Sass variable.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute